# Let $C$ be a chain of prime ideals in $R$. Show that $\cup_{P\in C}P$ and $\cap_{P\in C}P$ are prime ideals of $R$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Question: Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $C$ be a chain of prime ideals of $R$.  Show that $\cup_{P\in C}P$ and $\cap_{P\in C}P$ are prime ideals of $R$.

Thoughts: I am thinking I should use Zorn's Lemma here, but I am not quite sure.  I was also thinking this is the Prime avoidance Lemma, but that only deals with a finite number of primes, and so I didn't know how to handle an infinite chain.

Comment: Simpler than that. Just the definition of prime. Assume that $ab\in \bigcup_{P\in C}P$. Then there is a $P\in C$ such that $ab\in P$. Since $P$ is prime, then $a\in P\vee b\in P$. it follows that $a\in \bigcup_{P\in C}P \vee b\in\bigcup_{P\in C}P$. Since $\forall P\in C,\ 1\notin P$, then $1\notin \bigcup_{P\in C}P$.

Comment: Even for an infinite chain, the intersection of its members is immediate.  And for an infinite chain, any element of the union is also in one of the members of the chain (which member is only finitely far along the chain).

Comment: For the intersection is similar. The only detail is that you get that $\forall P\in C,\ a\in P\vee b\in P$ and from that you need to deduce that one is in all $P$. For this note that one of the two cases must happen at a cofinal subset of $C$. Then that case will happen for all $P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the definition of prime. Here's a sketch. Let $a, b \in R$ be arbitrary. (I'm going to assume that the chain $\mathcal{C}$ is non-empty.)

**Intersection.** Suppose $ab \in \bigcap_{P \in \mathcal{C}} P.$ Then, $ab \in P$ for *every* $P \in \mathcal{C}$. Thus, given any $P$, either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. (Now, there's the issue that some primes *could* contain $a$ and not $b$ while others contain $b$ and not $a$, we would want to ensure that one of them is in *every* prime in $\mathcal{C}$.)
Now, if $a$ and $b$ are both in every prime $P \in \mathcal{C}$, we are done. Suppose that that is not the case.
Then, there is a prime $P_0 \in \mathcal{C}$ which contains one and not the other. WLOG, assume $a \in P_0$ and $b \notin P_0$.
We now claim that $a \in P$ for all $P \in \mathcal{C}$.
Indeed, given any such $P$, there are two cases:

1. $P \subset P_0$. Then, $b \notin P$ and thus, $a \in P$.
2. $P_0 \subset P$. Then, $a \in P$.

(This is where we have used that $\mathcal{C}$ is a chain.)

---

**Union.** This is easier. Suppose $ab \in \bigcup_{P \in \mathcal{C}}P$. Then, $ab \in P$ for some $P \in \mathcal{C}$. But $P$ is prime and thus, either $a \in P$ or $b \in P$. In turn, $a \in \bigcup P$ or $b \in \bigcup P$. (We didn't use the chain condition but we need that to know that the union is an ideal.)

---

In both cases, you have to now check two more things: Both are ideals and are not all of $R$. The latter is easy since $1 \notin P$ for all $P$.
For the former, it is easy in the case of intersection (indeed, you don't need the chain condition). It is not too difficult for the union either but you need to use the chain condition now.